# Problema em CSS

Tags: html, css

Galera, estou com um problema, eu sei que isso é funcional, porém nunca funcionou comigo.

Segue o código:

**HTML**

```
<section class="menu-departamentos">
    <h2>Departamentos</h2>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Blusas e Camisas</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Manga curta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Manga cumprida</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Camisa social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Camisa casual</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Saias</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vestidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sapatos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bolsas e Carteiras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acessórios</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-departamentos li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

A minha dúvida deve ser bem simples.

1. `li ul` separados por espaço -> Qual o nome que se da para isso?
2. `li,ul` separados por vírgula -> Qual o nome que se da para isso?

O meu problema de fato é... consigo fazer alterações em css utilizando `li,ul` NORMAL, PORÉM, utilizando `li ul`, que é o que eu de FATO preciso, ele NUNCA altera.

**Browser utlizado:** Google Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Seletor separado por espaço é chamado de **seletor descendente**, significa que ele vai pegar por exemplo todos os `ul` que é filho de `li` que é bisneto de `.menu-departamentos`.

Seletor separado por vírgula é usado **pra aplicar o mesmo estilo a dois ou mais seletores**(por classe, id e tag), sem a necessidade de repetição de código.